# Let $G$ be a group and $K\le G, H\le G$. If there exist $x,y\in G$ such that $xK\subseteq yH$, then $K\le H$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group, and $K \leq G$, $H \leq G$. If there exist $x,y \in G$ such that $xK \subseteq yH$, then $K \leq H$.

Proof: Let $k \in K$. $xK \subseteq yH \implies xk$ is a coset representative of $yH$, so $xkH = yH$

That's as far as I've gotten...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $xK\subseteq yH$, $K\subseteq x^{-1}yH$. So, since $e\in K$, $e\in x^{-1}yH$. That is, $y^{-1}x\in H$. So, its inverse, which is $x^{-1}y$, also belongs to $H$, and therefore $x^{-1}yH$ is simply $H$. So, since $K\subseteq x^{-1}yH$, $K\subseteq H$.

Comment: The exercise is to show $K\le H$, not just $K\subseteq H$.

Comment: @Shaun What's the difference? Both $K$ and $H$ are subgroups of $G$ and $K\subseteq H$. Therefore, $K\leqslant H$.

Comment: Ah, yes, I see now. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

From your argument, you have shown that $y^{-1}xk \in H$ for every $k \in K$.

In particular, it holds for the identity element $e$, which lies in $K$ because $K$ is a subgroup.

Thus we have $y^{-1}x \in H$. It follows that $k = (y^{-1}x)^{-1} \cdot (y^{-1}x) \in H$ for any $k \in K$.